# Deactivate StreamBuilder when first landing on page

Tags: flutter

I have a top navigation bar. One of the tabs body contains a Streambuilder that has a function that is called in it's builder. I don't want the StreamBuilder to build when I first click on the tab but after clicking on the tab I'd like the Streambuilder to become active again. I'm thinking of using logic in the builder ...

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
   if (snapshot.hasData && tabCondition) { //not sure how to implement tab conditionality 
                 
       play();
    }
    return Container();
    })
```

Comment: What I understood is you want the `StreamBuilder` to be active when you visit the particular tab the second time. And it should stay inactive when visited the first time. Is that right?

Comment: I have read the question many times, and I cannot know exactly what you want,Give more details on the subject

Comment: @Jigar Patel ..Sorry for being unclear! Basically I have a beep sound every time an item is added to my SB. This is called in the builder method of the SB. But when I click on the tab(with the SB) the beep sound goes off(obviously because builder is triggered) which I don't want. I'm looking for a way to disable the builder when   I click the tab.

Comment: @faroukosama Sorry for being unclear! Basically I have a beep sound every time an item is added to my SB. This is called in the builder method of the SB. But when I click on the tab(with the SB) the beep sound goes off(obviously because builder is triggered) which I don't want. I'm looking for a way to disable the builder when I click the tab